# How to add Resource Id to ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api

Сan anyone explain how to add a resource identifier to `ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder` class? I saw only `WithClientSecret` `WithTenantId` methods but did not WithResource or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to this document which explains the method that supports [ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.confidentialclientapplicationbuilder?view=azure-dotnet#moniker-applies-to) and Resource Id is not supported in this.

for example method supported ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder are `WithClientSecret(String),WithCertificate(X509Certificate2)`